# Local Django server redirects to Sentry server

Tags: python, django, sentry, raven

I had setup a local django server along with celery which used to be at `127.0.0.1` (I could adjust the port when running the command `python manage.py runserver <port>`).

Then, I wanted to set up Sentry for my app. I followed the quickstart instructions for doing this. This is what I have modified in my `sentry.conf.py`

```
SENTRY_URL_PREFIX = 'http://sentry.localhost'
SENTRY_WEB_HOST = 'localhost'
SENTRY_WEB_PORT = 9000

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

And this is what I have modified in my `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'sentry',
    'raven.contrib.django',
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat'
)

SENTRY_CLIENT = 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.DjangoClient'

RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn' : 'http://private:public@localhost:9000/2?timeout=10',
}

from sentry.conf.server import *
```

I had to add the `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` because otherwise `python manage.py raven test` would fail due to suspicious header. And I had to add `from sentry.conf.sever import *` because otherwise I would get errors with raven with some sentry variables not being set. After setting up Sentry, I could access it from `127.0.0.1:9000`.

But, I cannot access my django app. Everytime I go to 127.0.0.1:8000, I get redirected to sentry login (which gives an internal server error after logging in as its not on port 9000). Also, looking at logs from console, I see a `SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_POST header` error if I don't put `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` at the end of my `settings.py` file.

How can I run both the django app and Sentry locally on the same IP (localhost) and on different ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are Django apps so they're going to want to run on port 8000 by default. However, the [`runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port) command accepts port as an argument, so you can pass a different port to one or the other depending on how you're running Sentry. `python manage.py runserver 9000` will run on that port. You'd just need to update your Sentry settings to use port 8000. Otherwise you can pass the port to Sentry's `runserver` command if you're using that locally.